# SQL Server 2017 (v14.0.2027) named pipes

Tags: sql-server, named-pipes

I can't connect to a SQL Server 2017 instance remotely through the default named pipe using SSMS.

I configured SQL server as following:

1. SQL Server network config -> SharedMemory and Named pipes are enabled, TCP/IP is disabled
2. Named pipe name is `\\.\pipe\sql\query` (which is the default, I believe)
3. 445 port is open
4. Remote connections are allowed on the SQL server
5. SQL Server Browser service is disabled (as we use default pipe name)

**Expected behavior**

The SSMS client can connect remotely to the SQL Server by specifying just a SQL Server instance name `MYINSTANCENAME`

**Actual behavior**

The SSMS client fails to connect with the timeout exception unless I explicitly provide the `np` prefix in the SSMS server name input box.

Like this -> `np:MYINSTANCENAME`

Comment: Have you enabled Named Pipes as a Sql Client network option on the client?

Comment: Yes, it's enabled

Comment: When managing the client protocols in SQL Server Configuration Manager there is seperate configuration for 32-bit clients and 64-bit clients, and you can use the Move Up and Move Down arrows to determine which of the protocols is the default one to use for each process model.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning You are right, but the problem is on the server-side. Changing client configuration didn't help, unfortunately.